# Getting Can't get attribute 'getImages' on <module '__main__' from '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn'>" when using a fastai model

Tags: python, deployment, gunicorn, fast-ai

Hey guys I am getting the no attribute error when running my ML model on a gunicorn hosted flask app.
Locally I just had to simply declare the function in the main scope to get things running,
how can I do that on a gunicorn hosted app?

how should I structure my fast ai models in the future to avoid this issue?

hre is the error
get attribute 'getImages' on <module '**main**' from '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn'>"

Answer (score 1):

figured it out,
had to add the following:

```
import __main__
def getImages(d): return##
__main__.getImages = getImages
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't know why.  Can you explain it?

Comment: the function getImage was in the main process when the model was build and that is where it expects the function to be when it run's even if it doesn't use it or does anything. That is my understanding. I am not sure if I am correct, I never got an explanation my self.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially how I've come to understand it since.  In training you're working in the __main__ namespace.  Then you load the model into a different project and that has its own __main__ namespace.  References to the function are in that namespace.  So, it will only find it if you explicitly add it to that namespace.

Comment: Are you adding this in the main.py file of your flask app? Also, is getImages a function that is defined within your model?

Comment: yes, I am. It is the function that was used to create the data block when training the fastai model. 

`dataBlock = DataBlock(

    blocks=(ImageBlock, CategoryBlock), 

    get_items=get_image, 
    splitter=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42),
    get_y=parent_label,
item_tfms=[Resize(192, method='squish')],
    batch_tfms=image_transformation
)`